# While parsing tags like in HTML/XML I want to initialize strtok for '<' but sometimes I need to handle just raw text

Tags: c, strtok

My problem is

```
char *text, *tag = "foobar";
if (tokenizedStr[0] == "<")
    tag = strtok((tokenizedStr), ">");
```

Sometimes the tokenized string should be permitted to not begin with a tag. Given that the next line

```
do {
```

is the start of a massive comparison loop ending in `while (tag = strtok(NULL, ">"));` i would like to know if there is any way to feed `strtok` the base string without having it advance past any characters? I'm implementing rudimentary formatting and line wrapping here is all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly: no, this is impossible with `strtok`.  You need significantly more powerful tools: [`lex`](https://github.com/westes/flex) and [`yacc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), and a properly-defined formal grammar for whatever you're trying to parse.  This will replace not only your use of `strtok` but most of the "massive comparison loop" you didn't show.

Comment: You're understanding is correct. "massive" may just be my euphimism for "not shown" but i think i can rework it to initialize later in it and keep dependencies down. Thanks

Comment: If you are bent on writing a lexer/parser by hand -- and I sympathize, I've done that myself a few times -- `strchr` and `strcspn` and manual copying of string tokens are probably going to be more useful to you than `strtok`.

Comment: I thought i was alone in having repeated this exercise. I remember how fast things got when I shunned library functions (which I knew less of then) altogether.